# Android - Get event for Android Message application whenever opened

Tags: android

In Android, I want to know if I can receive the event whenever I open Android Message Application?

I tried get task in foreground but that didn't work in service as for that service has to continuously poll

Kindly guide

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can achieve this is by polling. No other way :(

Answer (score 1):

> I can receive the event whenever I open Android Message Application?

No.

First, there are thousands of Android device models, spanning hundreds of manufacturers. There are dozens upon dozens of "Android Message Application" pre-installed across the device models, as manufacturers often provide their own. There are also hundreds of "Android Message Applications" available on the Play Store and elsewhere. You have no great way to know what apps are and are not "Android Messaging Applications", though you could try to examine `<intent-filter>` structures and deduce which ones might meet your requirements.

Second, there are no events posted to ordinary Android SDK apps when other apps or their activities start. Even some of the polling techniques that you mention will not work on Android 5.0+, and any that still *do* work represent bugs that should get fixed. Google is locking down this information for privacy and security reasons, such as to help prevent OAuth hijacking attacks like [this one](http://money.cnn.com/2015/07/09/technology/android-game-facebook/).

Comment: Something we can identify through package name. Like for example for Skype I will get package name "com.skype.application" whenever it is in foreground, can be something done like that